# Angular Update Doom from Controller without using $Scope

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

i really need some help here with angular...  this time i have no idea at all.

I want to update my doom, Angular Element using my controller.

For example:

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="UpdateController as UC">
{{UC.updateText}}
<button ng-click="UC.updateIt()"/>
</div>
```

js code:

```
angular.controller('UpdateController', function(){
this.updateText = 'Text to Update';

this.updateIt = function(){
// Here i need to update this.updateText.

}
});
```

I have tried:

```
angular.controller('UpdateController', function(){

var updateText = this;
updateText.newText = 'Text to Update'

this.updateIt = function(){
    updateText.newText = "my new text";
}
});
```

and i change the HTML as well to {{UC.updateText.newText}}

But it doesn't work, i  can see all my changes in console.log(); 
I have tried multiple ways. using Watch (error, digest already running). and other variables and calls.

Can someone explain me how to do it using 'this.' ?

I don't wan't to use $scope, if i use $scope TAG it updates with no problem, but i don't wan't to give up using the 'this.' tag.
Also, i don't want to use element.angular, or jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use `this.updateText = 'my new text'`. It is however recommended to use a variable that is assigned to `this` as this may change when within a function inside the controller.

```
angular.controller('UpdateController', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.updateText = 'Text to Update';

    vm.updateIt = function(){
        vm.updateText = 'my new text';
    }
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuQfvau7xfoyPYvdCUWx?p=preview)

Comment: It worked! thank you! i just had to put my function inside the same variable!!